# Can Poltergeist and Capybara be used standalone?

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

Assuming I have PhantomJS installed on Mac OS X, can I write a plain old Ruby script (no Cucumber, no RSpec) to drive Poltergeist? In other words, I want to require some gems, set the Capybara driver to Poltergeist and then start calling page.fn() to pull down pages, analyze contents, etc?

UPDATE: Here is what I have created. It seems to work.

```
require 'awesome_print'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist

include Capybara::DSL

visit '/'

page.driver.network_traffic.each do |request|
  ap request.response_parts
end
```

I know the naked include is bad, but I am just hacking at the moment before I encapsulate this in a class.

Feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can definitely use capybara & poltergeist without cucumber or rspec. What you have looks like a pretty good start.

However, you will probably want to use some standardized testing library to provide you with assertion methods & a test runner so you don't have to recreate all that stuff yourself. Your primary options are:

- test/unit (now minitest under the hood)
- minitest/spec (a spec-like wrapper for minitest)
- rspec

Here are the capybara integration instructions for each:

- [test/unit](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitestspec)
- [minitest/spec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitestspec)
- [rspec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-minitestspec)